# I want to write cypress script to intercept an API response and store the json response in a variable, and extract specific values from the response

Tags: api, cypress, cypress-intercept

My goal is to land on a page

Ex: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

When I land on this page a particular API is hit, I want to intercept that API and store the json response in a variable and extract specific values from the response.

I have tried this code but it fails after waiting for 5 seconds:

```js
describe('Intercept API response', () => {
  it('Stores the response in a variable', () => {
    let responseData;

    cy.intercept('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').as('getData');

    cy.visit('https://www.example.com')
      .then(() => {
        cy.wait('@getData')
          .then((xhr) => {
            responseData = xhr.response.body;
            console.log(responseData);
          });
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: In the Cypress runner, are you seeing the intercept being hit at all? Your intercept may be getting hit before you tell Cypress to wait for it.

Answer (score 4):

If you change the test slightly, it works without a hitch!

```js
describe('Intercept API response', () => {
  it('Stores the response in a variable', () => {
    let responseData;

    // lets try to intercept the actual domain

    cy.intercept('GET', 'http://www.example.com').as('getData');

    cy.visit('http://www.example.com')
      .then(() => {
        cy.wait('@getData')
          .then((xhr) => {
            responseData = xhr.response.body;
            console.log(responseData);
          })
      })
  })
})
```

logs this to console

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example Domain</title>

</head>

<body>
<div>
    <h1>Example Domain</h1>
    <p>This domain is for use in illustrative examples in documents. You may use this
    domain in literature without prior coordination or asking for permission.</p>
    <p><a href="https://www.iana.org/domains/example">More information...</a></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Given that your example works, what else can you tell us about the test that might allow us to see the issue?

Comment: If you need clarification from the poster, you should post a comment

Comment: The answer is useful, it points out the pattern for intercepting is correct.

Comment: The answer is useful, but I brought this up because they were asking for clarification at the end of their answer. If they need more clarification from the poster, they should post a comment.